# Trying to put tokens from a file into a string array excluding blank spaces

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I'm trying to split all the strings in the file and put them into an array and exclude all blank lines and tabs but I am still getting blank entries in my array when I print it. The blank spots are where ever a new line is made but I figured they would have been removed with the characters I have in my aa array.

```
        string line;
        List<string> tokenList = new List<string>();
        char[] aa = new char[] {' ', '\t', '\r', '\n'};
        do {
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            foreach(var test in line.Split(aa)) {
                if(test != null) {
                    //System.Console.WriteLine(test);
                    tokenList.Add(test);
                }
            }
        } while(sr.EndOfStream != true);
        foreach(var toke in tokenList) {
            System.Console.WriteLine(toke);
        }
```

Example file I'm reading:

```
DECLARE
    my_char CHAR;
    my_vchar VARCHAR2 ( 6 ) :='JOHN';
    my_bool BOOLEAN := NULL ;
    total   SMALLINT(5);
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( total) ;
    mychar :=' ';
    total &total;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT ( my_vchar) ;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT ( mychar) ;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT ( total) 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE ;
ENDl \
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
line.Split(new string[] { " ", "\t", Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

instead of

```
line.Split(' ', '\t', '\r', '\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting on both return and linefeed.  The two bytes together in windows based machines are used at the end of a line.

Answer (score 0):

*I think* this is what you are looking for:

```
    string line;
    List<string> tokenList = new List<string>();
    char[] aa = new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' };
    do
    {
        line = sr.ReadLine();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
        {
            foreach (var test in line.Split(aa, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                if (test != null)
                {
                    //System.Console.WriteLine(test);
                    tokenList.Add(test);
                }
            }
        }

    } while (sr.EndOfStream != true);

    foreach (var toke in tokenList)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(toke);
    }
```

1) Have added the following to make sure you aren't trying to handle empty lines:

`if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))`

2) Have changed your foreach `.split` to:

`foreach (var test in line.Split(aa, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))`